# Number of into functions from one set to the other

Tags: combinatorics

Let $f : \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \} \to \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ be an into function such that for at least one $i \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, we have $f(i) = i$. How many such functions can we have?

First I tried by doing this by taking cases, like for exactly one $i$, exactly two $i$'s etc...But that turns out to be too long, and not just that, I am even getting lost in midway. So, how to do this, in a short way?

---

Note that I hadn't heard of anything like an *into* function before reading this question. On searching, I couldn't find much. Only [one site](http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/set-relations-functions/functions-one-one-many-one-into-onto.aspx) had defined it:

> Mapping (when a function is represented using Venn-diagrams then it is
>   called mapping), defined between sets X and Y such that Y has at least
>   one element 'y' which is not the f-image of X are called into mappings

$     $

Comment: Try turning the problem on its head. See if you can calculate the number of functions that DON'T map ANY element to itself. Then you can find the answer to your question with a small calculation.

Comment: I had also tried that. Didn't get anywhere though. If that into condition wasn't there, then it was very easy - just a degeneration. But with that condition, I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: How many functions are there in total? (Hint: how many choices for $f(1)$, for $f(2)$, ...?)
Next, how many functions are there that do *not* satisfy $f(i)=i$ ever? (Hint: how many choices for $f(1)$, for $f(2)$, ...?)

Comment: @GregMartin, that gives me the number of all functions that satisfy $f(i) = i$ for at least one $i$. That is $3125 - D(5) = 3081$. But how to deal with the into constraint?

Comment: Can you write the definition of an "into function"?

Comment: Yes, what is an "into" function? Do you mean "onto"?

Comment: "Into function" is not common terminology. There are three possibilities I can think of: (1) you read "let $f$ be a function from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ into $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$" and thought the "into" had a precise meaning, but it simply signifies the codomain and nothing more; (2) you're referring to an injective function; (3) it's supposed to be "onto" (surjective). In case (2) and (3) (which are equivalent, since the domain is finite) you'd be looking at "derangements", a nontrivial but well-studied type of function.

Comment: @woso, I have already stated the definition, as I found on the website. I also stated that I had never heard of that kind of term ever before.

Comment: As you have stated it should fix at least one $i$ with out loss of generality assume $1$ is fixed so we are actually looking for $f :\{2,3,4,5\}\rightarrow \{2,3,4,5\}$ now another point is that $f$ must leave out some element in $\{2,3,4,5\}$ basic case would be $f( \{2,3,4,5\})= \{2,3,4\}$ how many maps are there now??

Comment: I had proceeded along those lines, however, after spending a lot of time doing that, I saw the definition again, and all the efforts crumbled - the definition of into (as given here) is: "$f$ must leave out *at least* one element". It became too, too long.

Comment: may be you should start with functions with $f: \{1,2,3\}\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$ how many maps do you think there exists with your condition ?

Comment: @Parth Thakkar, base on that definition it seems "into" means "not onto", so we are looking for "not onto" functions with at least one "fixed point"; anyway maybe if you write the final result it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1:** number of all functions is $5^5$ (?).

**Hint 2:** number of those functions that do not satisfy the given condition is $4^5$ (?).

so the desired number of such functions is:
$$5^5-4^5=3125-1024=2101.$$

---

And if we are looking for "not onto" functions with at least one "fixed point" the desired number is:
$$(5^5-4^5)-(5!-D_5)=2101-76=2025.$$